# Static content - Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I know similar questions have been asked before but I still can't get this to work.

I'm having a spring MVC web-site with file tree that looks like this:

```
webapp\
     resources\
        style.css
        myimg.png
        post.html
     Main.html
```

My servlet sets Main.html to be its main page and it loads correctly with the style and pic I mentioned using these tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources\style.css"
    media="screen" />
<img src="resources\myimg.png" style="padding-left: 25px" />
```

Also I define in my config (I'm using class configuration):

```
public class ApiServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

When I call `post.html` from `Main.html` the file is loaded without the style and the image. Not sure what more should I do in order to load it correctly.

post.html has these tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<img src="myimg.png" style="padding-left: 25px"/>
```

Also, i tried with `resources\style.css` and `resources\myimg.png`

The controller call looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/view", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
public String getPostByIdHtml( @PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
    return "/resources/post.html";
}
```

Main.html has a link that looks like: `http://mysite.com/100/view`

What more should I do in order for the css and image to be loaded.
Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
Following the comment, that's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  
    /Main.html

Not very interesting I guess. I have the initalization in Java code, probably more interesting:

```
public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext container) {
    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    context.register(ApiServletConfig.class);

    final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("api-dispatcher",
                                                                        new DispatcherServlet(context));

    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/api/*");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your web.xml

Comment: I edited the post. I don't use configuration in the web.xml but with implementation of `WebApplicationInitalizer`. It does the same thing

Comment: "*Also, I tried with `resources\style.css` and `resources\myimg.png`*". This is plain wrong. You're regarding it as the local disk file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page changes the url. It looks something like:

`http://[web-server]/[app-name]/api/post/100/view`

Because I'm making a json call.

If I'm changing the css path to something like this, it works!

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../resources/style.css" media="screen" />`

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use c:URL for all (not exterm) references in the jsp. With c:URL you can write the URL relative to the application, the tag will add the remaining parts automatically. Then you will not have any problems (with relative URLs) if someone change the current url

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your css and image files are on folder resources, which looks like the case, as per your folder structure, I believe you should update your code as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/style.css" media="screen" />
<img src="/resources/myimg.png" style="padding-left: 25px"/>
```

Comment: Are you able to access your css file with the following links: http://mysite.com/resources/style.css or http://mysite.com/<your-app-name>/resources/style.css ? Of course mysite.com is whatever machine your app is hosted on

Comment: Ok, what if you move post.html to the same folder where you have Main.html, and keep using the code provided in this answer? Does it work? Please note you will have to update your Controller so it reads    `return "/post.html"`;

Comment: I tried this as well. But using Google Chrome debugger I found the problem! I'll add an answer. Thanks a lot for your help! You've been a great help!